# How to use regular expressions within QGIS Actions

Tags: qgis, postgis, actions, regular-expression

I have stored html links in a column of a postgis layer. There are a few entries which have multiple links stored in one cell (blank separated).
I have to use the `firefox.exe` to open the links in multiple tabs. This doesn't work with `Open` type,

I can open these links with:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" [% "link" %]
```

An entry of link looks like:

```
file:///H:/going/goingfurther_01_page.html
```

Now I want to use the same column to open the link in this way:

```
file:///H:/going/page.html
```

I tried:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" [% regexp_replace("link",'goingfurther_[0-9][0-9]_' ,'') %]

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" regexp_replace([% "link" %],'goingfurther_[0-9][0-9]_' ,'')
```

But QGIS can't open this.
The first replace expression works with the field calculator.

Comment: I'm afraid/think you mix a bunch of things together (html, rdbms+gis, geo-data, qgis) which are not desigend for a cooperation in that way. You could consider three components: 1. a web server (generate/delivering html) 2. with gis capabilities (handle the data for positions and links when clicking) and 3. a application logic (the regexp stuff, to get next html page), to do that

Comment: There is a `Insert Expression` button in the Actions Form. So I assumed regex will be an option to create actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Into the blue untested**: Following the instruction in the [qgis tutorial](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/de/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html) it seems, that the call `Open` `file_location/file.type`, to start an application like a browser, is connected with the default settings for the mimetype `type` in your OS. May `Open` is a wrapper around [`os.startfile..`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/206215/3338646) for example...

One way to solve the problem could be, to register the application [`firefox` to the content of to `text/html`](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/972634).

A second opportunity, you could follow, is shown in paragraph 6.4.5 of the same [qgis tutorial](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/de/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html). The action statement (here a call to show the internal web componenet `QWebView`):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; \
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView; \
myWV = QWebView(None); \
myWV.load(QUrl('http://wikipedia.org/wiki/[% "name" %]')); \
myWV.show()
```

could be adopted in a `pythonish` way to start the firefox application.

```
import os; \
app  = "'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' "; \
file = [% regexp_replace("link",'goingfurther_[0-9][0-9]_' ,'') %]; \
os.system(app+" "+file);
```

Or

```
import subprocess; \
subprocess.call([app, file]); \
```

if you have [problems with the spaces and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204049/3338646).

Remarks:

1. I add some line breaks to the action code.  The sign `\` at the end of each line indicates, that the code has to be written in one line in the action field.
2. The QGIS Application / Map setup works a little bit like a dynamic web application with GIS capabilities. This could be done in a more [transparent way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Use_in_web_applications) but with much more effort.

Comment: It works, thank you. I have to define `file = u'[% regexp_replace("link",'goingfurther_[0-9][0-9]_' ,'') %]'` to get it work. Otherwise there is a syntax error due to the link address. Explained here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56579/view-html-field-data-with-qt4-browers-as-a-qgis-run-feature-action-tool